# Git push to private server never finishes

Tags: git, server, push

I am trying to set up a git server on my raspberry pi over HTTP. I cloned it successfully on my PC, but when I make a commit and push it to the remote it never finishes. I tried both from the terminal and from Tortoise Git and the result is the same. [image: PushImage]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in "[Setting up Raspberry Pi as a git server](https://dev.to/kodaman2/setting-up-raspberry-pi-as-a-git-server-230f) " from [Fernando B](https://twitter.com/KodamanFB), using SSH could be a viable alternative (provided SSH is enabled in `sudo raspi-config`).

Regarding HTTP, that depends on the HTTP server running on your Raspberry Pi, but you could try one [very easy to install: Gitea](https://docs.gitea.io/en-us/install-from-binary/): it would both provide an HTTP listener, and a quite complete front-end for your Git repositories.

Comment: Thank you. I will try and tell you what happened. I've used various resources and I've probably messed up the apache config

Comment: @DenisRizov Exactly, which is why I recommend Gitea: no config, no setup: just an executable to run.

Comment: Just installed Gitea, and it's amazing mate. Thank you very much